# Simulate random sample from defined probability density function

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, distributions

Suppose I define a function in mathematica that has all of the properties of a valid probability density function.  Would it be possible to have Mathematica simulate a random sample of a given size of values from this PDF?  For example,  if I define a function which is the PDF of a beta distribution, can I collect ten thousand "instances" or random samples from this PDF for statistical analysis?  If so, how would I do this?  Despite my example, I am specifically interested in being able to use my own defined PDF, not necessarily a built-in one that Mathematica already has.

Comment: seen Oleksandr Pavlyk's _Creating Your Own Distribution_ in [Wolfram Conference 2011](http://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2011/mathematics-and-statistics.html)?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`ProbabilityDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution) for this. Your example pdf:

```
pdf = PDF[BetaDistribution[1.2, 3.2], x];
pdf //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  4.554304156477517` (1-x)^{2.2`} x^{0.19999999999999996`} & 0<x<1 \\
>  0 & \operatorname{True}
> \end{cases}$

And using [`ProbabilityDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution):

```
RandomVariate[ProbabilityDistribution[pdf, {x, 0, 1}], 10]
```

> {0.0287507, 0.274103, 0.1581, 0.524414, 0.496944, 0.0579204, 0.204799, 0.230026, 0.140485, 0.438046}

Comment: This is helpful, thank you.  But suppose I want to use my own PDF, (say one that I have defined as a function), not one that Mathematica has built-in.  How would I do that?

Comment: @ereHsaWyhsipS Just replace `pdf` with your chosen function.